# Laravel API - Authentication works just after reloading the page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, laravel-passport

I am trying to build a Single Page Application (SPA) using VueJS as a front-end and Laravel as a back-end.
I am using [laravel's passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport) to manage the authentication tokens etc.

---

**The problem**: After login I have to reload the page to be successfully authenticated.

---

**Login method**

```
data() {
   return {
       email: '',
       password: '',
   }
},
methods: {
   login() {
       var data = {
           client_id: 2,
           client_secret: '****************************',
           grant_type: 'password',
           username: this.email,
           password: this.password
       }
       // send data
       this.$http.post('oauth/token', data)
          .then(response => {
               // authenticate the user
               this.$store.dispatch({
                   type: 'authenticate',
                   token: response.body.access_token,
                   expiration: response.body.expires_in + Date.now()
               })
               // redirect after successful login
               if (this.$route.query.from)
                    this.$router.push(this.$route.query.from)
               else
                    this.$router.push('/feed')
               })
        }
    }
```

**Get the user information from the backend** (just works after refreshing the page)

```
setUser () {
     // this route throws 'unauthenticated' error 
     // and works only after refreshing the page
     this.$http.get('api/users/') 
          .then(response => {
              this.$store.dispatch({
                   type: 'setUser',
                   id: response.body.id,
                   email: response.body.email,
                   name: response.body.name
               })
          })
     }
}
```

**Vuex store**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        isAuth: !!localStorage.getItem('token'),
        user: {
            id: localStorage.getItem('id'),
            email: localStorage.getItem('email'),
            name: localStorage.getItem('name')
        }
    },
    getters: {
        isLoggedIn(state) {
            return state.isAuth
        },
        getUser(state) {
            return state.user
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        authenticate(state, { token, expiration }) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', token)
            localStorage.setItem('expiration', expiration)
            state.isAuth = true
        },
        setUser(state, { id, email, name }) {
            localStorage.setItem('id', id)
            localStorage.setItem('email', email)
            localStorage.setItem('name', name)
            state.user.id = id
            state.user.email = email
            state.user.name = name
        }
    },
    actions: {
        authenticate: ({ commit }, { token, expiration }) => commit('authenticate', { token, expiration }),
        setUser: ({ commit }, { id, email, name }) => commit('setUser', { id, email, name })
    }
})
```

---

**Laravel route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@users');
});
```

**Laravel function**

```
public function users(Request $request)
{
   return $request->user();
}
```

---

**The error message**
[image]

When I reload the page the error message disappears and I am successfully authenticated.

---

I would be very happy for any kind of help!

Comment: more important than the resposne would be your request header for the call that fails. can you verify the token is actually sent? From what I see you are simply missing setting the default request headers after the login. Happens probably once at start of the app and therefore works after reload

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly the problem! I did not send the header with every request!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Frank Provost I figured out the answer. In case anybody else comes across the same problem:
I was not passing the token with every request.
I had to change this

```
Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + Vue.auth.getToken()
```

to this

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + Vue.auth.getToken())
    request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
    next()
})
```

Now, everything works as expected - no need to refresh the url.